# Is the faceplate screw hole on power outlets connected to ground?

Tags: receptacle

Many ganged outlets have at least one screw hole whose primary use is to attach a faceplate.  Assuming the outlet is properly grounded, if a mounting holes exists, is it required to be connected to ground?

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed sufficiently to bet your life on. Judging by some of the questions we see on here the chances are slim that anything is ever grounded properly ;)

Comment: No since grounding would depend if the outlet is property grounded to the box(which might be plastic).  Quite often the screws are painted/coated so the screw probably will have poor electrical connection(so no safe ground).

Comment: I've slightly edited my question to make the intent more clear.  As in, assuming everything is wired correctly and there is no other fail state in play, if that hole should be connected to ground.  Or if the manufacturer, for example, is allowed to just tap part of the plastic housing.

Comment: You changed your question - from 'guaranteed' to 'required'. What are you trying to discover, whether you *should* or whether the last person in there actually *did*. 'Should', yes; 'did', who can say?

Comment: Your question was very clear to me. Until you edited it. Please provide a picture of what you're talking about now. As far as I'm aware, every NEMA 5-15 receptacle (your "standard" duplex receptacle) has a hole between the outlets for mounting a faceplate.

Comment: @Tetsujin To be clear, assuming the outlet was properly grounded, i.e. the person who installed it correctly attached the ground wire to the outlet, is it required that any screw holes use for mounting also be grounded?  Or are they allowed, for example, to just be tapped into the plastic frame.

Comment: @FreeMan I might be mixing up terminology here.  But I see plenty examples of what I'd consider "standard" outlets without a mounting hole.  Example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-Residential-Grade-Grounding-Duplex-Outlet-White-10-Pack-M24-05325-WMP/100357041

Comment: Ah, gotcha. You have to use a different type of cover plate for those.

Answer (score 3):

If everything is wired correctly then that threaded hole should be grounded as shown in the picture in MonkeyZeus's answer.

If you are asking if you can ground something by using that hole, that becomes more difficult, since the connections might not be good enough to be safe, paint on the screw, too small of a wire.

There were adapters for three prong plugs to fit two prong outlets in the past using that screw/hole, but I think they have been banned for being unsafe.

Comment: No, they are not banned.  Amazon still sells them and I'm sure you can pick them up at your local hardware store.  They are UL listed:  https://www.amazon.com/prong-Polarized-Grounding-Power-Adapter/dp/B00JZX5ZRG   That being said, if it's old wiring with just two wires...no way can it be grounded!

Comment: They are banned/not approve for use in Canada.  Think they might be banned in some of the states also, so would need to contact the local overlords.  https://novascotia.ca/lae/electricalsafety/esbadapterplugs.asp

Comment: *"if it's old wiring with just two wires...no way can it be grounded!"* If it's old wiring with two prong plugs, it could very well be grounded - via a grounding wire in the cable, via BX shield, or via metallic conduit. But you have to check. Yes, there was a time when the grounding wire was there, but three-prong plugs were "outlandish" or otherwise unpopular, so the receptacles were still 2-prong.

Comment: @Steve Amazon will sell all manner of illegal stuff (or to be more precise: third-party sellers in "Amazon Marketplace", but the UX is identical to Amazon's own stuff, right down to Prime shipping).   However you are correct.  What is banned (in UL White Book areas, anyway) is the variety that uses a pigtail wire instead of a tab. No idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Guaranteed? Nothing is guaranteed.

Probable? No clue, take one apart and check.

This outlet specifically seems to support your conjecture.

[image]

[Source](https://www.electrical-forensics.com/Receptacles/ElectricalReceptacles.html)

> are they required to be connected to ground?

No clue, you'd have to read the requirements for getting an outlet UL listed. Keep in mind that  UL requirements may change over the years so an older outlet could be considerably different than a modern one.

Comment: The specification is called out in the UL White Book.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine do you have a link to the UL White Book? I'd gladly add such info to my answer.

Comment: Here's the index. https://code-authorities.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/UL-White-Book.pdf The documents proper are copyrighted and must be purchased.